# Changing readonly variable declared in super class inside subclass SWIFT

Tags: swift

I am an old objective-c developer trying to get my feet dirty in Swift, but I had the following problem:

we have a super class

```
class MySuper  {
     private(set) var myReadOnlyVar = true
}
```

and then I have subclass of MySuper

```
class Subclass: MySuper {
     func myFunc() {
         super.myReadOnlyVar = false        // error
     }
}
```

Any workaround I can make here ? I know that swift has no protected access, but it should have something similar.

Comment: I've just ran your code and it works just fine http://i.imgur.com/rsoyPXa.png

Comment: did you forget private(set) @MariusFanu ?

Comment: If you look at the image I've added, you'll see that the variable is with `private(set)` access modifier, @Basheer_CAD http://i.imgur.com/ZBPH0dr.png

Comment: @MariusFanu, thanks for trying the code out. The problem is, on Playground things are different, because you are defining both classes in the same file, the private var is available to other classes in this file and can be changed, now if you are outside the class, you can set myReadOnlyVar freely, try it out

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `Subclass` implementation to this

```
class SubClass: MySuper {
    func myFunc() {
        super.setValue(false, forKey: "myReadOnlyVar")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out and let you know

Comment: you are using KVC to change private variable, which is not what I am looking for. I will wait for a better answer, but your answer is appreciated and upvoted